# WebApi.Hal - HttpPost always send null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem with HttpPosts when using WebApi.Hal.
I am posting like this:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/TestWebApi/api/test/test2/",
            data: {
                "reference": bookingref,
                "leadname": leadpax,
                "_links": {}
            },
            contentType: "application/hal+json",
            //dataType: "application/hal+json",
            success: function(data, status) {
                alert("POST: Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('POST: Status: ' + xhr.status + ', Error Thrown: ' + thrownError);
            }
        });
```

and picking the post up like this:

```
    public LoginDetails PostTest2([FromBody]LoginDetails value)
    {
        return new LoginDetails();
    }
```

LoginDetails inherits from Representation but value is always null.
Any ideas?

Comment: How does LoginDetails look? Can you confirm PostTest2 is being hit?

Comment: If its a `new LoginDetails()` , it will be null. You are returning a fresh new object there.

Comment: it will be null if LoginDetails doesn't match the input data object which you are passing through the ajax post.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, Originally I was installing the Hal formatters like this...

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonHalMediaTypeFormatter());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new XmlHalMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I changed it to this...

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new XmlHalMediaTypeFormatter());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonHalMediaTypeFormatter());
```

So that it keeps the old formatters but inserts the Hal ones before the default formatters (giving them a higher precedence).